# Converting char array to integer c programming

Tags: c, arrays, compare, min

The Problem: The user enters a time in 24 hour format. The Array has different times listed also in 24 hour format. I would like to compare the number entered by the user to the time that is closest to the time entered by the user. Whatever number is closest to the time entered by the user is to be displayed on the screen. I've been working overnight at my company job and trying to understand the programming behind this. Can anyone help me? By the way, I just began this C Programming class. If you see anything that looks like C# code, it's because I haven't learned enough yet. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int hours, mins; //24 hour time to be entered by user

    int bestTime = scanf("%d:,%d", &hours, &mins);  //best time for user departure

    char* depart [8] = {"8:00", "9:43", "11:19", "12:47", "14:00", "15:45", "19:00", "\0"}; //times available for departure

    int counter; //count number of times to loop
    printf("Please Enter The Best Time For Your Flight In 24 Hour Format.\n");
    scanf("%d:,%d", &hours, &mins);

    for(counter = 0; counter <  ; counter++){
        if(bestTime < depart[counter]){
            bestTime = depart[counter];
        }
    }

    return bestTime;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d:,%d",`...smells fishy...

Comment: `int bestTime = scanf`....check what is the return value of `scanf()`...

Comment: For the comparison I would convert the times into total number of seconds (multiply hours by 3600, minutes by 60 add together).  Then you make the comparison between 2 integer values, and can easily compute the difference between them and hence find the nearest one

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya indeed, but working with integers is easier than HH:MM eg, user enters 13:00 and there could be a time of 12:58 and 13:03 or user enters 15:00 and times are 09:12 and 21:11.. makes for a more complex search, integer versions its a simple subtraction wrapped in `abs`

Comment: `for(counter = 0; counter <  ; counter++){` is clearly missing some character(s) after the `<`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that converts a string of format "hh:mm" into minutes from "00:00". And then use that to do all the comparisons.

One implementation of the function can be

```
unsigned int str_to_mins(const char* t) {
    return (unsigned int) (
        ((t[0] - '0') * 10 + (t[1] - '0')) * 60 
        + (t[3] - '0') *10 + (t[4] - '0')
    );
}
```

Call this function on all your strings. They will give you unsigned integers. Use that to find the number closest to the one entered. (Convert your input to also this format in similar way).

Just to be clear scan your input as

```
char input[10];
scanf("%s", input);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The idea:
>
> - After getting the time from the user, convert everything to minutes.
> - Get every element of your departure array, convert it to integers using atoi().
> - Convert to minutes the departure times and put them inside an array of integers.
> - Now compare the total number of minutes entered by the user with every total you have in your array. That's simple; you compare the
>     absolute values of the subtraction of the departure total from the
>     input total. The lowest absolute value is your closest. For that, I
>     wrote a function that returns the index of the closest element inside
>     the array.
> - I display the equivalent closest value from your initial departure array of strings.
> - NB: I assume you have 7 departure times.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

int findClosest(int * , int);

int main(void) {

    int hours,mins,total; //24 hour time to be entered by user
    char computationHours[3],computationMins[3];
    int computationHoursInt,computationMinsInt,computationTotal;

    int bestTime; //best time for user departure
    int index;
    char * depart[8] = {
        "8:00",
        "9:43",
        "11:19",
        "12:47",
        "14:00",
        "15:45",
        "19:00",
        "\0"
    }; //times available for departure
    int departures[7];
    int counter; //count number of times to loop
    printf("Please Enter The Best Time For Your Flight In 24 Hour Format.\n");
    scanf("%d:%d",  & hours,  & mins);
    total = (hours * 60) + mins;
    for (counter = 0; counter < 7; counter++) {

        if (strlen(depart[counter]) == 4) {
            //Like 8:00
            strncpy(computationHours, depart[counter], 2);
            strncpy(computationMins, depart[counter] + 2, 2);
            computationHoursInt = atoi(computationHours);
            computationMinsInt = atoi(computationMins);
            computationTotal = (computationHoursInt * 60) + computationMinsInt;
        } else {
            //Like 19:00
            strncpy(computationHours, depart[counter], 2);
            strncpy(computationMins, depart[counter] + 3, 2);
            computationHoursInt = atoi(computationHours);
            computationMinsInt = atoi(computationMins);
        }
        computationTotal = (computationHoursInt * 60) + computationMinsInt;
        departures[counter] = computationTotal;
    }

    index = findClosest(departures, total);
    printf("Closest timing is: %s", depart[index]);
    return 0;
}

int findClosest(int values[], int n) {
    int dist = abs(values[0] - n),closest;
    int size = 7;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        if (abs(values[i] - n) < dist) {
            dist = abs(values[i] - n);
            closest = i;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```